# Is it possible to retrieve specific data from firebase ( ionic )

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, ionic5

I am trying to retrieve the user data from Firebase Realtime Database, however instead of retrieving the current user information, all of the data is being shown. This is my code for the typescipter.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-editaccount',
  templateUrl: './editaccount.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./editaccount.page.scss'],
})
export class EditaccountPage implements OnInit {

  users = [];
 

  constructor(
    private auth: AngularFireAuth,
    private afDB: AngularFireDatabase,
 
    ) { 
      afDB.list('/users').valueChanges().subscribe(result => {
        this.users = result; 
        console.log(this.users);
      });
  
    }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

This is my code for the html page.

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Edit Account Details</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  
  <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let users of users" reorder="true">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>
        <h1>
          {{users.name}}
        </h1>
        <p>
          {{users.email}}
        </p>
        <p>
          {{users.number}}
        </p>
        <p>
          {{users.date}}
        </p>
      </ion-label>
      <!-- List reorder button -->
      <ion-reorder slot="end" class="ios hydrated"></ion-reorder>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-item-sliding>
</ion-content>
```

Ultimately i am trying to edit the account details. I have added the images of my firebase real time database and the authentication

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you give us a link to know how you DB is designed?.

Comment: I have updated the question and added the DB design

Comment: Can you also give us the data that you're retrieving?

Comment: I am trying to retrieve date, email, name and number

Comment: Sure, but when you said "instead of retrieving the current user information, all of the data is being shown". Can you send a screenshot of the "all of the data" part?